# SQL Server Collation effect on query

Tags: collation

SQL Server running 2016 on VM.  The collation is set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Restored a database into the server and it is a collation of Latin1_General_CI_AS.

During testing all was good and the server became production.  Unfortunately a test was overlooked and that involves update with subquery and join which fails "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference".

I understand this is referencing a column in an outer query,  but nothing in theory has changed in the application or the data.

I am left wondering the obvious collation difference between the source server which was Latin1_General_CI_AS and as indicated the destination server which now has SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.   Is this enough to cause this kind of issue,  or should I ignore and look to the data.

I have performed a profiler and seen the following fail:

```
`select l.LoanID, l.LoanRef, l.FundID, l.RateType, (select Max(r.ReqDate)
from PaymentRequests r
where (r.ReqLoanTransactionID > 0)
and r.loanid = l.loanid
group by l.LoanID) LastMadeReqDate,
(select count(r.PaymentRequestID)
from PaymentRequests r
where ((r.ReqLoanTransactionID is null) or (r.ReqLoanTransactionID = 0))
and (ReqDate >= @P1)
and r.loanid = l.loanid
group by l.LoanID) NoofUnmadeReqs
from loans l
',N'@P1 datetime','2023-06-01 00:00:00'`
```

Sadly the application is years old and totally unsupported.  I am unable to access the source code.
I would appreciate any opinion on this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: That error is nothing to do with collation. That's a badly constructed query, the group by should be on the outer table.

Comment: What is the purpose of those `group by`s? In both cases you've already used the `where` condition to limit to a single `loanid`. Presumably you could change both `group by l.loanid` to `group by r.loanid` to get rid of that error, but I would expect the same result just removing the `group by`s completely.

Comment: Hi,  yes the Group by appear to be poor.  But they are hard coded into the application and there is nothing I can do about that.  End result is a query I have no control over which has suddenly started to fail.  I have run profiler and seen this query.  Hence I asked about collation

Comment: @MrTG You mentionend in your question "sqlserver". Then add the tag to your question. Why? Well see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Forgive the oversight please.

Answer (score 0):

Tempdb use the instance level collation. In your case you have aggregate and sort operations which use tempdb. Ideally, you should have the same collation for user database and the instance to avoid collation conflicts.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question.  Intention is to setup a new test environment with all the same collation and determine whether this will resolve the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has not resolved the situation.  I provided a VM and SQL 2016 With correct collation.  
It has not made any difference to the output when we try to run an update of base rate.  Therefore I will need to have a rummage around in the database on assumption, maybe data is the issue …

Comment: Can you paste the error message please? Also, did you check the column collation?